# Get Attribute Value - Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have created a new attribute on magento 1.9 and called category_grouped. Now I am trying to get it's value on catalog page by using getAttributeRawValue but all I am getting is an ID. How could I get the value name rather than the ID?  Below is my code. Thanks

```
<?php $attributeId = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')-
>getAttributeRawValue($_product->getID(), 'category_grouped', $storeId);?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The getAttributeText gets the value / name of the given attribute while getAttributeText return in this case the ID.

```
 $attributeValue = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->load($_product->getID())
    ->getAttributeText('category_grouped');
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set attribute value by using below code

```
$product->CategoryGrouped();
```

Thanks